# Geocoding in ArcGIS desktop and use the shapefile in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-online, decimal-points

I want add 60 addresses in point format to my map in ArcGIS online. So what I did was use ArcGIS Desktop (10.2) to geocode them, exported them as a shapefile, and imported them to the online map. First of all, is this the way I have to do it? I mean can I do it directly from ArcGIS online?

The second problem is I wanted to have 60 points. But I end up with fewer points, like 15-20. I found the problem is that somewhere during this procedure ArcGIS Desktop decided to round the X and Y values to 6 decimal places. I checked the geocoding results and changed the decimal places to 10. Then I checked the shapefile and I found in the shapefile's attribute table, X and Y just have 6 decimal places. I was not able to change the decimal place in attribute table. I tried to add new field and set the decimal places to 10 and then use filed calculator. It did not work!

I tried to geocode them using batchgeo.com, then I imported them as X and Y coordinates. I made sure Xs and Ys are set to have 10 decimal places. Agian the same problem when I exported it as a shapefile.

Any suggestions? The original file is addresses, including address, city, state and ZIP.

Comment: you are geocoding or reverse geocoding? you have an address or an x,y pair?  AGOL will allow drag and drop geocoding with xls, csv cant remember which is supported now. just drag it onto your map.

Comment: I just have the address and I'm trying to add them as points to AGOL. so if I drag and drop the X and y coordinate it will work? I will try it now.

Comment: @BradNesom I just have the address and I'm trying to add them as points to AGOL. I just tried to add one of the addresse, after geocoding, to the map the way you said, noting happened! I mean I made CSV file with i record, with X and Y and dragged and dropped it in the AGOL and it accepted it (no errors) but it is not showing up on the map! one more thing is when I checked the configuration setting for the fields in AGOL, the maximum number of decimal point are 6! I mean you cannot have 7 or more, just 6

Comment: I believe agol will let you drag and drop the xy event (which is what the XY data would be). A better solution is to drop the ADDRESS if you have them in a file try that.

Comment: Also, I don't know your particular situation, but for most geocoding operations (especially if you're using a standard commercial geocoding service rather than some in-house build custom geocoder), 6 decimal places on X&Y precision is going to most likely be all you need.  I can't imagine many situations where you would need more than 6 decimal places for standard address level precision.  What is more likely happening with you only getting a few points back is that the geocoding is likely not finding matches for all the addresses, you may have bad address data as an input.

Comment: @user2856159 I need to show couple of houses in the same street, it means their location is not that different

Comment: @user2841098 well at 6 decimal places the precision is measured in milimeters, so.... I don't think you're going to have a couple of houses within a few millimeters of each other.  Some basic reference on decimal degree precision [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

Comment: To address the decimal place issue, you may want to look at the data type for whatever field is storing that coordinate information. If it's a float, you can only store out to six decimal places - you'd need a double if you wanted more. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000001m000000 But also note as other comments point out, for locating houses you probably don't need more. And geocoding services probably know this. As John points out, your missing results are probably geocoding failures (no match) rather than coordinate precision issues.

Answer (score 1):

On [ArcGISOnline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Add_layers/010q0000009v000000/) you can find information on how to add data to the map.
It sounds as though you have a spreadsheet with addresses.
You can add that as a [csv file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Add_layers/010q0000009v000000/) to your map and it will create the points for you with the addresses.
You can also add a file with xy coordinates in the same way. but you will not get address information created doing that.  If it already has address information with the coordinates then you would need to configure it to make sure it used the xy rather than geocoding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just drag and drop a CSV file right onto the map if you are using Chrome or Firefox.  It will automatically geocode the points.